# Probability Question Random Variable Median

Tags: probability, random-variables, median

[image]

I have not idea where to start with this question can someone point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if the median position of the math majors is $i$, $2$ math majors have to be placed in the $i-1$ positions below $i$ and the remaining $2$ have to be placed in the $10-i$ positions above $i$.

The probability that the median is $i$ is the product of the numbers of ways of doing these two things, divided by $10!$ for the total number of equally probable possibilities.

If $p_j$ is the probability that $X=j$, the mean of $X$ is $\sum_{j=3}^8 j\times p_j$, which you can easily do after the first part.

Comment: so P(x=3) would be i=3, 3-1 = 2 and 10-3 = 7 so it would be       (2 choose 2) x (7 choose 2) / 10! = .000006

Answer (score 0):

There will be symmetries that make the work easier: once you have found the first three probabilities, you will know the last three.  And because of the symmetry, you will not even need the probabilities to find $E(X)$.

As an example, let us calculate $\Pr(X=5)$. There are $\binom{10}{5}$ equally likely ways to place the math majors. To have the median of the math majors equal to $5$, we choose $2$ of the first $4$ places to put a math major, and $2$ of the last $5$ places. This can be done in $\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}$ ways.

Thus $\Pr(X=5)=\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}}$.

The calculations for $X=3$ and $X=4$ are very similar, and symmetry takes care of $6,7,8$.

Comment: I was think about it as ranks = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 P(X=5) would be something like M,M,S,S,M,S,S,S,M,M and median of math would be 5 and you could rearrange the first 4 ranks 4! way 5th rank just 1! and then ranks 6-10 5! ways is this correct thinking?

Comment: Instead of using the technique I used, you can use a sample space of the $10!$ permutation. You still have to make sure that there are $2$ M exactly in the first $4$, and $2$ in last $5$. You will end up with $\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}5!5!$. Now divide by $10!$. Same result as in answer above, somewhat more work.

Comment: ok yeah the hyper-geometric seems alot easier

Comment: It has a similar structure to the hypergeometric, but actually it is different. Not a lot easier really than something you were sort of proposing, but I think you may have had some details not quite right. By the way, for $X=3$ the numerator is $\binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2}$. and for $X=4$ is is $\binom{3}{2}\binom{6}{2}$. For $8$ it is the same as $3$. for $7$ same as $4$, for $6$ same as $5$.